# Scala how to pad a month with leading 0 using datetime library. Do not want to use string formatting

Tags: scala

I see want something like this:

```
val SomePattern = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM")
val folderLocation = s"location/${SomePattern.print(d)}"
```

Is there a Scala library that pads a zero to a month?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate, java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter  

DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM").format(LocalDate.now)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-

Comment: Almost never use `LocalDate`, use `ZonedDate` with `UTC` instead.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh If the use-case calls for `LocalDate`, use it. I don't agree with the "almost never" qualification, it really depends on what you're doing.